# Codeigniter: Ignore form input with only spaces

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Greeting,

So I have a form, and am doing form_validation for an email field just like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','trim|valid_email|xss_clean');
```

if my input is somthing like `test@example.com` with spaces in begin or/and end of my input, trim work great.

But if my input contains only spaces  , a validation message occur :
`You have to input a valid email address`.
How can I handle this so if the input is only spaces just ignore it as no input ?

Comment: Why don't you clean up the form before submitting it?

Comment: That's what i'm asking for.

Comment: Keyword: *before*. You can't do that with PHP, so it's not what you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do trim before validation

```
$_POST['email'] = trim($_POST['email']);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','valid_email|xss_clean');
```

Comment: oops! Thank u, that's very easy.

Comment: You can Add Trim in rule: $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','trim|valid_email|xss_clean');